# Rails: render layout false to fix js issue also skips the layout when pressing back

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, layout

Some of my js.erb templates won't render unless I use

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render layout: false }
end
```

As I wanted to generalize the fix, I used the following in my base controller:

```
layout proc { request.xhr? ? false: 'custom'.freeze }
```

But since then, I've notice that quite often, when I press the back button, the layout won't be rendered.

I'm obviously doing something wrong here, what's happening in either case and what's the proper way to handle this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't be an issue in recent versions of Rails as long as (1) your layout has the mimetype in the filename (e.g. `custom.html.erb`) and (2) your XHR request properly requests the JS type. Which seems to be the case here.

Also are you using turbolinks? Your back request may be interpreted as an XHR even though you didn't expect it to. I'd recommend against using the second approach 'back' actions are often unpredictable since they can be cached. Instead use the `responders` syntax as described in the Rails docs: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Responder.html

Comment: Good call, my filename was custom.slim instead of custom.html.slim. Thanks a lot!